# What is this syntax: union{}?

Tags: c, unions

```
void display_binary_float(unsigned int ui) {
  union {
    unsigned int ui;
    float f;
  } uif2;
  uif2.ui = ui;
  printf("binary: %08X float: %g\n", uif2.ui, uif2.f);
}
```

1) What is union? There was no manual entry for it, for some reason. Couldn't find the doc on google.

2) Why is `uif2` at the end of the function union? Shouldn't it be something like `union uif2 {}` or is this a C thing?

Comment: What did you search for? I found a good reference searching for "union c". It's a totally standard C language feature.

Comment: Your google must be broken. Mine came up with a whole page of relevant results for your search, too.

Comment: @Doug Which search engine are you using? I recommend finding a better one!!

Comment: Any good C reference will deal with unions; usually in the same section `struct` is dealt with. What 'maunual' are *you* referring to?

Comment: @Doug a google search for "c programming union" will get you plenty of hits, but "C language union" will work better. And virtually every C book, tutorial, and "manual" ever written mentions unions. And the placement of `uif2` is no different than it would be if it were a (anonymous) struct rather than a union.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29), it say:

> In C and C++, untagged unions are
>   expressed nearly exactly like
>   structures (structs), except that each
>   data member begins at the same
>   location in memory.

I'm sure the documentation for whatever tools you have will tell you all about unions, you just haven't found that section yet.

Answer (score 1):

A union allows you to treat a block of memory as different variables/variable types. Each variable shares the same memory, and the total amount of memory used by the union is the amount used by the largest member.

Accessing union members is done exactly as you would access structure members. But while structures contain members that each contain their own memory, members in a union share the same memory and so one or more member may invalid.

Obviously, you can't store multiple values in a union. But, for cases where you want one data type in one case and another data type in another case, it provides a convenient way to store one of those different data types.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (2), `uif2` is a *variable* declared with a type that happens to be a union. The union has no name, so it's called an "anonymous" union. You can do the same with `struct`, too:

```
struct {
    int a;
    char *b;
} foo;
```

This declares a *variable* called `foo` which has a type of the given `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

It's a C keyword, like enum or struct. A union is basically a way to layer several types of variables in the same space. Look it up in any decent C reference.

Answer (score 0):

union is like a struct, but with only one field that can be accessed by multiple names. So in your case, `uif2.ui` and `uif2.f` both access the same memory location.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9zewe0d(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

union here means the unsigned int ui and float f are sharing the same memory space.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `union` has been well covered.

The answer for your syntax question is that `union { unsigned int ui; float f; }` is a type, a `union` with members `ui` and `f`.  In an initialization, the values do go after the variable name, but this is a definition rather than an initialization.